# Binding Textbox.Text to Service-Based DataBase

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm creating a money flow program in Winform. Now i have to bind textbox to Service-Based DataBase (LocalDB) but it gives error (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.').I'm not fimiliar with databases so i don't know how to code but im using this

```
        private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {                                           
                    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\dotex\Desktop\tst\Manager\Manager\ManagerFile\MoneyTransactionsFile\MoneyMovements\MoneyMovementDataBase\moneydatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
                    sc.Open();
                    SqlCommand sd = new SqlCommand("insert into Name(@AddedMoney)", sc);
                    sd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddedMoney", TextBox.Text);
                    sd.ExecuteNonQuery();// this line gives the error
                    sc.Close();
            }
             Else
             {
             
             }
```

This is a photo of my database for now. [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz877.png) 
If u need any information to fix just write comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a straight SQL question, unrelated to the application or the `TextBox`.

When you write an `INSERT` statement in SQL, you can omit the list of column names if and only if you provide a value for every column in the correct order. Your table has two columns but you are providing only one value, so you it won't work. You need to specify the column you want to insert into and the other column will be set to its default value. If you do omit the column list, you still need to include the `VALUES` keyword.

You are also specifying `Name` as the name of the table but, in your screenshot, it's actually named `Table`. Both are atrocious names and you should change it to something that indicates the purpose of the table.

```sql
INSERT INTO MyWellNamedTable (AddedMoney) VALUES (@AddedMoney)
```